# Why is the window not being drawn?

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, archlinux, wayland

When I run the code below, the window does not appear. There are no errors in the output.

```
// main.cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  glfwInit();
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

project(app LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
    glfw
)
```

OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Kernel: 6.5.7-zen1-1-zen
WM: sway 1.8.1

```
~/ pacman -Qs glfw 
local/glfw-wayland 3.3.8-1
    A free, open source, portable framework for graphical application development (wayland)
```

I'm waiting for an application window with the name specified in the code on my monitor screen.

Comment: Try making something else appear, such as Hello World to stdout. If that works, try it in other places in your code until you narrow down the problem statement.

Comment: @GetSet I tried it. The main loop works quite well. True, the window should have appeared before it began.

Comment: Always check the result of a function, what's the value of `window`? Since you specify a monitor, is your goal to create a windowed fullscreen? **Note:** _"To create a full screen window, you need to specify the monitor the window will cover."_ and _"For full screen windows, the specified size becomes the resolution of the window's desired video mode."_ and _"the supported video mode most closely matching the desired video mode is set for the specified monitor"_ (see: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3555a418df92ad53f917597fe2f64aeb).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük The window test and the initialization function test completed without failure. That's why I removed the check code. I don't need a full screen app. I assumed that if I specified the monitor explicitly, something would change in a positive direction, but this action was unsuccessful. The window did not appear and still does not appear. I have already seen this documentation. This code was written using it.